# Is "Dynamic Link Library" an actor?

Tags: uml

I have a Software.

User will use software to process file,

But my software will use a other software or "Dynamic Link Library" of 3rd party.

Is "Dynamic Link Library" of 3rd party an actor?

Comment: "Actor" refers usually to participants of a use case. How a use case is implemented in code, and if it uses 3rd party DLLs or not is usually an implementation detail of the black box "use case". DLLs "live" at a completely different level of abstraction.

Comment: I typically use "the system" for such use cases, as in "The system shall take periodic backups of the data to insure data integrity."

Comment: It really depends on what you are trying to communicate in your diagram, but i'd say its rare to treat something like a dll as an actor

Answer (score 4, accepted):

Probably not, "Actors" in UML and other design methodologies are generally humans, or machines automating a humans job.

If you have a process which is initiated via a message through this 3rd party though, you might consider it an actor. As presumably some user or automated user action has precipitated that message

Comment: Yes, I send message to Dll of 3rd party to process and return result. Is it actor?

Comment: no. I would say not

Comment: @DT, is the processing done by the 3rd-party code part of the responsibilities of your system? If yes, then the 3rd-party code belongs inside the system boundary and is not an actor.

Comment: And if it is not part of the responsibilities, then "the third party" is the actor. A DLL is a software artifact, not an actor. People are actors, Organizations are actors, "the outside world" is an actor, systems can be actors.

Answer (score 1):

I think your DLL is *not* an external system (it's a software library inside the system being developed).

To show a counter-example where external systems *are* actors, here's an example from [Larman](https://g.co/kgs/2YQrtv):

[image]: